# HTTP Status 500 - Error when trying to invoke method from java file

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to run an application using tomcat 8.5.23 but I keep getting the same error over and over again. I am keep receiving an HTTP status 500 error every time I am trying to start the tomcat and open my local host.
This is the error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/index.jsp] at line [19]. And here is my file (index.jsp and IntagramWB.java)

```
<html>    
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="Web Services">
<meta name="keywords" content="JSP, Bootstap, HTML5">

<!-- including the jQuery file to the bootstrap -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- including the bootstrap file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<title> My Restful API</title>
<body>
    <%@ page import = "com.mywebservices.InstagramWB" %>

    <% InstagramWB insta = new InstagramWB(); %>
    <% String details = insta.getDetails(); %>


    <script>
        var name = JSON.parse("<%= details %>");
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = details.data.full_name;

    </script>

    <h1 id = "name"> </h1>
    <h2>Last place: </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to invoke a method from a java class. Here is my java file:

```
package com.mywebservices;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class InstagramWB
{
    public InstagramWB()
    {}

public static String getDetails()
{
    // Variable for the access token
    String accessToken = "269891473.1677ed0.a60ed893764d4c5";
    String replyInsta = "";
    String jsonInsta = "";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    try
    {
        // Endpoint to get the details of the user
        String endpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token="+accessToken;

        // establishing the connection to the endpoint
        url = new URL(endpoint);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();
        is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        while ((replyInsta = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            jsonInsta = replyInsta;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonInsta;
}
}
```

Also here is my folder structure if its needed.
[image: Folders structure]

and Exceptions:
[image: exceptions]

Comment: Have you compiled and deployed your class? It has to be in `WEB-INF/classes` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the 'Root Cause' section of your stack trace. The actual error is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: InstagramWB

Basically, on line 19 when you are doing ...

```
InstagramWB insta = new InstagramWB();
```

... it cannot find the .class file for InstagramWB.

Are you sure your war file has been correctly created, and the InstagramWB class is available inside it? Try unzipping the war file using any unzip utility e.g. Winzip, WinRAR etc., and check if you can find the .class file for this class inside it.

Comment: The war file is automatically unzip once I put in the the /tomcat/webapps and start the tomcat. I checked it and the .class file is there.

Comment: Well, for whatever reason, the classloader is not able to find it, that is why you are getting this error.

See this article about classpath and classloading in Tomcat. This might give you some directions to debug the reason further:

https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath